# Is <p> a block-level or inline-level element?

Tags: html

I had a question when I came across the HTML 4.01 DTD:
In the strict DTD, a `<p>` element is defined as
`<!ELEMENT P - O (%inline;)*          -- paragraph -->`
but I thought that `<p>` was a block-level element, and all (maybe almost all) user agents define `<p>` as a block-level.

So is `<p>` a block-level or inline-level element?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

It is a block level element. What that DTD is saying is that `<p>` tags can only contain inline elements.

Comment: And how to get around this limitation of <p>?

Answer (score 16):

Of course it is.

The following are defined as block-level elements in XHTML 1.0:

```
* address - Address
* blockquote - Block quotation
* center - Centered block
* dir - Directory list
* div - Generic block-level container
* dl - Definition list
* fieldset - Form control group
* form - Interactive form
* h1 - Level-one heading
* h2 - Level-two heading
* h3 - Level-three heading
* h4 - Level-four heading
* h5 - Level-five heading
* h6 - Level-six heading
* hr - Horizontal rule
* isindex - Input prompt
* menu - Menu list
* noframes - Frames alternate content
* noscript - Alternate script content
* ol - Ordered list
* p - Paragraph
* pre - Preformatted text
* table - Table
* ul - Unordered list
```

The following elements may also be considered block-level elements since they may contain block-level elements:

```
* dd - Definition description
* dt - Definition term
* frameset - Frameset
* li - List item
* tbody - Table body
* td - Table data cell
* tfoot - Table foot
* th - Table header cell
* thead - Table head
* tr - Table row
```

The following elements may be used as either block-level elements or inline elements. If used as inline elements (e.g., within another inline element or a p), these elements should not contain any block-level elements.

```
* applet - Java applet
* button - Button
* del - Deleted text
* iframe - Inline frame
* ins - Inserted text
* map - Image map
* object - Object
* script - Client-side script
```

**[More Info Here](http://www.cs.sfu.ca/CC/165/common/ref/wdgxhtml10/block.html)**

Comment: "Of course it is" could be construed as unnecessarily belligerent…

Answer (score 5):

The p element should not contain any other block element, although it is a block element itself. If you put block elements inside a p, you will, for example, have a hard time trying to apply css rules to those block elements.

Answer (score 4):

It is block, but like any other block element the CSS display property can make it behave in a few ways, including inline or inline-block.

Answer (score 3):

Block level

Source: [here](http://htmlhelp.com/reference/html40/block.html)