# dropdown inside of paragraph moves out in browser

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

**HTML Markup:**

I am using a dropdown inside of a paragraph in the markup shown below. When I try to load the page in a browser the dropdown markup appears outside of the paragraph.

```
<div class="logoBar">
        <section class="container">
            <p><span>SITE NAME</span><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span><span>Main Page</span>

            <font class="pull-right">
                <div class="dropdown">
                <span class="dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true"><span>myemail@gmail.com</span><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down"></span></span>
                  <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
                    <li><a href="_/components/php/signout.php">Sign out</a></li>
                  </ul>
                </div>
            </font>
            </p>
        </section><!-- container -->
      </div><!-- End logoBar -->
```

So, that's what is my doubt. Please note that I have already created the markup I wanted to use for my project. So , I am not worried for the layout but I just when through this case and I wanted to know the reason.

**Why the dropdown doesn't stay inside of the paragraph in browser?**

Comment: The dropdown div isn't inside the p tag, so I'm not sure what you're saying. Can you add your CSS? Also, what's with the font tag?

Comment: best practice -  `<p>` element is only for text - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/p

Comment: Also `font` has been deprecated and should no longer be used.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't used to `div` or `form` inside `p` used to `DIV` tag

> `<p>` elements don't allow block level elements inside `</p>`
>
> The P element represents a paragraph. It cannot contain block-level
>   elements (including P itself).

used to this

```
<div class="logoBar">
        <section class="container">
            <div><span>SITE NAME</span><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span><span>Main Page</span>

            <font class="pull-right">
                <div class="dropdown">
                <span class="dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true"><span>myemail@gmail.com</span><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down"></span></span>
                  <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
                    <li><a href="_/components/php/signout.php">Sign out</a></li>
                  </ul>
                </div>
            </font>
            </div>
        </section><!-- container -->
      </div><!-- End logoBar -->
```

Answer (score 0):

p is an inline element and div is a block level evement.

use p tags inside div it should work fine in all the browser if you follow w3c standards

Comment: now check to this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2789727/is-p-a-block-level-or-inline-level-element

Comment: Factually incorrect...a `p` tag is a **block-level** element. - https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/p